# Unity5 How to create a floor

Tags: c#, platformer, unity

This may be a may be a very basic question but I have a 32x32 tile of grass for a 2D platformer I'm making. Is there an easy way to duplicate the tiles and lay them out? or will I have to copy and paste the tile a 100 times and adjust each one individually just to make a level?

Comment: Of course, you could copy it ten times, then select those ten and make nine copies, giving you 100. But most of us write something that will automatically create tiles based on some map data.
See [Unity procedural TileMap generation without creating gameobject per tile](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102629/unity-procedural-tilemap-generation-without-creating-gameobject-per-tile)

Comment: Thats still a pain in the ass :D. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I have answered a similar question , where you can populate different tiles as per need, using a 2d matrix to hold the information.
Its very basic but you can build on top of it , to suit your needs :)

Link:-
[Generate static 2D Tilemap from array](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105941/generate-static-2d-tilemap-from-array/105947#105947)